# Unable to access Artemis GUI when listening on 0.0.0.0

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am initializing brokers in 2 different ways. One that listens on `0.0.0.0` and the other that listens on the node IP i.e. `172.29.245.17`.

Broker 1 :

```
[root@amq-1 apache-artemis-2.4.0]# bin/artemis create --name BROKER-1 /var/tmp/BROKER-1  --user admin --password admin --http-host 0.0.0.0 --http-port 8080 --allow-anonymous
```

Broker 2 :

```
[root@amq-1 apache-artemis-2.4.0]# bin/artemis create --name BROKER-2 /var/tmp/BROKER-2  --user admin --password admin --http-host 172.29.245.17 --http-port 8080 --allow-anonymous
```

As you can see, the only difference is which IP to listen on. One is open to all(0.0.0.0). The other listens only on 1 specific IP().

There is no problem accessing the GUI of Broker-2 (one listening on `172.29.245.17`)

Now when I start Broker-1 (listening on `0.0.0.0`), I get redirected to `/console/jvm/connect`

[image]

ERROR states ::

```
[Core] Operation unknown failed due to: java.lang.Exception : Origin http://172.29.245.17:8080 is not allowed to call this agent
[Core] ActiveMQ Management Console started
[Window] Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined (http://172.29.245.17:8080/console/app/app.js?0d5300a336117972:16:14366)
[Window] Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined (http://172.29.245.17:8080/console/app/app.js?0d5300a336117972:16:14366)
[Window] Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined (http://172.29.245.17:8080/console/app/app.js?0d5300a336117972:16:14366)
[Window] Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined (http://172.29.245.17:8080/console/app/app.js?0d5300a336117972:16:14366)
```

For Broker-1 , the `jolokia-access.xml` states ::

```
<restrict>

    <cors>
        <!-- Allow cross origin access from 0.0.0.0 ... -->
        <allow-origin>*://0.0.0.0*</allow-origin>

        <!-- Check for the proper origin on the server side, too -->
        <strict-checking/>
    </cors>

</restrict>
```

For Broker-2, the `jolokia-access.xml` states :

```
<restrict>

    <cors>
        <!-- Allow cross origin access from 172.29.245.17 ... -->
        <allow-origin>*://172.29.245.17*</allow-origin>

        <!-- Check for the proper origin on the server side, too -->
        <strict-checking/>
    </cors>

</restrict>
```

I am unable to figure out why the issue occurs when Im trying to listen on `0.0.0.0`. Any ideas ?

All other configurations are default. I have not modified any other config.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that your `jolokia-access.xml` on Broker-1 is using this:

```xml
<allow-origin>*://0.0.0.0*</allow-origin>
```

However, in your browser you are attempting to access the console via `172.29.245.17:8080` which isn't allowed based on your `jolokia-access.xml`. Therefore you need to either change your browser to connect to `0.0.0.0:8080` (which will only work when the broker/console is running locally) or change the `jolokia-access.xml` to allow the IP:port you're actually going to use to connect.

You can read more about the `jolokia-access.xml` in the [Jolokia security documentation](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/security.html).